# How to get featured image's width and use elsewhere in template?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm wondering if it's possible in the single.php template to use the width of the post's featured image elsewhere in the page.

What I'm trying to do is add a div element on the page with the same width as the post's featured image (which will always be a different width).

If anyone has any ideas, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the following. First, add this piece of code to the template:

`<?php $image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "thumbnail" ); ?>`

$image_data will now return an array containing the url, width, and height ([function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)). To get the width, you might do this:

`<?php $image_width = $image_data[1]; ?>`

In your specific example, after adding the two pieces of code above to your template, you might do this:

`<div style="width:<?php echo $image_width; ?>">`

Is that helpful?

Comment: That's incredibly helpful, worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome! Glad you joined us on the WordPress Stack Exchange :).

Comment: @jonathan-wold This only gets the data for the 1st image in the loop, not all post thumbnails